# HttpClient c#- how to get dynamic content data?

Tags: c#, get, httpresponse, dotnet-httpclient, dynamic-content

For example, i need to get price values from https://www.futbin.com/22/sales/415/erling-haaland?platform=pc, that are located on the 'sales-inner' table.
The problem is that HTTP Response returns results without loaded prices.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.futbin.com/22/sales/415/?platform=pc");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

How to get these data?

Comment: Assuming the content is loaded via an API after the page itself has loaded, you can find the API request in your browser's debugger under the Network tab. Otherwise you'll have to learn how to scrape single page applications (which will involve allowing the page's Javascript content to execute - perhaps using a browser automation tool such as Selenium or Puppeteer)

Comment: Data is loaded to this page through AJAX requests. Check https://www.futbin.com/22/getPlayerSales?resourceId=239085&platform=pc and https://www.futbin.com/getPlayerChart?type=live-sales&resourceId=239085&platform=pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you have mentioned in the question renders the view. To get the actual data you need to check the below URLs. Please note that I have got the below URLs from the debugger window but you can check docs if APIs are already provided.

https://www.futbin.com/22/getPlayerSales?resourceId=239085&platform=pc
https://www.futbin.com/getPlayerChart?type=live-sales&resourceId=239085&platform=pc

```
public async Task Main()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(@"https://www.futbin.com/22/getPlayerSales?resourceId=239085&platform=pc");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(responseString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting html without results because they are loading the data when the page loads. Open dev tools in your browser and check the network tab, there you'll see that they pull the data from:

https://www.futbin.com/22/getPlayerSales?resourceId=239085&platform=pc

That returns a list of all the prices with dates in json.